# How to get rid of duplicate links using python

Tags: python, duplicates, set

I'm new at coding and I'm trying to scrape all unique web links from https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html. I've tried to put the links into a set but the output comes back as {'/'}. I don't know any other way to get rid of duplicates. Below is my code. Thank you for you help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib
import urllib.request
import requests

with urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html') as response:
    html = response.read() 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    links = (link['href'])

link = str(link.get('href'))
if link.startswith('https'):
    print(link)
elif link.endswith('html'):
    print(link)
unique_links = set(link)
print(unique_links)
```

Comment: What is the 3output of the intermediate if statements?

Comment: I think `set(link)` is unnecessary. You would want to append to your list with `unique_links.append(link)`. Also, you want something like `list(set(unique_links))` if you want to remove the duplicates, and then have a list for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say all the links are stored in a list called `links1`. Here is how you can remove duplicates without the use of `set()`:

```
links2 = []
for link in links1:
    if link not in link2:
        links2.append(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your set only contains the final link, declare the `set()` earlier, then `add` to it.

```
unique_links = set()

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    link = str(link.get('href'))

    if link.startswith('https'):
        print(link)
    elif link.endswith('html'):
        print(link)

    unique_links.add(link)
print(unique_links)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the set outside the for loop, then add to set inside the loop.

```
link_set = set()
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    link_set.add(link['href']
```